# Evaluate property from properties file in Spring's @EventListener(condition = "...")

Tags: spring

I would like to make the execution of an event handler dependent on whether or not a property is set to `true` in a properties file.

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class, condition = "${service.enabled}")
public void onStartup() { }
```

However, this does not seem to work. I am getting the following error on startup:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 1): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'

Is it possible to use a property from a properties file as a condition here?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is condition argument is expecting a SPEL.
This works try it out.

In your bean where you have this `@EventListener`, add these lines

```
public  boolean isServiceEnabled() {
    return serviceEnabled;
  }

@Value("${service.enabled}")
public  boolean serviceEnabled;
```

change your declaration of evnt listener like this

```
@EventListener(classes = ContextRefreshedEvent.class, condition =  "@yourbeanname.isServiceEnabled()")
public void onStartup() { }
```

change yourbeanname with the correct bean name .

Comment: I thought that in a SpEL expression you could reference a property by using the syntax `#{ ${numberProperty} + 2 }` ([source](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language)) and that (assuming `numberProperty` is `1`) it would evaluate to `3`. But it turns out that `condition` doesn't allow that otherwise valid SpEL expression. Your workaround does indeed work, and looks like what I had come up as a workaround as well.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with different contexts. Another point is SPEL is not evaluated for properties in application.property files . check it out. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value

Comment: this is absurd!

Comment: @Aubergine what is absurd?

Comment: that in 2020 EventListener cannot resolve ${property}, I had to reference a ConfigurationProperties bean and the most hilarious part of that Spring gives these types the longest names in Spring ecosystem -> Full property path + Full package name. It's just sooo stupid.  And this Q&A are the only in entire web which actually attempt to do something sensible inside 'condition'.

Comment: It doesn't work this way, because the EventListener evaluates the condition before the @Value is injected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying experience (with Spring Boot 2.4.2 on Java11).

In my case I had the `boolean` property in a `@ConfigurationProperties` class anyways in the same java file and still struggled a bit. First the `@ConfigurationProperties` need to be annotated as `@Component` to actually be a valid `Bean` and can be used in SpEL.
And I had to use the same long attributeName for the `ConfigurationProperties` in the `Service` itself and the `EventListener` Annotation for the Bean resolution to work fine. I needed some the `ConfigurationProperties` values also in another place of the `Service`, that's why they needed to be (Constructor) `Autowired` as well...

So this worked for me:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my.custom.path")
@Component //Important to make this a proper Spring Bean
@Data //Lombok magic for getters/setters etc.
class MyCustomConfigurationProperties {
    boolean refreshAfterStartup = true;
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor //Lombok for the constructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyCustomConfigurationProperties.class)
@EnableScheduling
public class MyCustomService {
    private final MyCustomConfigurationProperties myCustomConfigurationProperties;

    @EventListener(value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class, condition = "@myCustomConfigurationProperties.refreshAfterStartup")
    public void refresh() {
       //the actual code I want to execute on startup conditionally
    }
}
```