# Execute Spring @EventListener based on a value from application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-listener, app.yaml

I would like the execution of the event handler to depend on whether the property is set to `true` or `false` in application.yaml file. I have three yaml files (test, dev, prod) and I have set the settings in them:

application-dev.yml

```yaml
page-cache:
  starting: false
```

application-test.yml

```yaml
page-cache:
  starting: true
```

application-prod.yml

```yaml
page-cache:
  starting: true
```

And I need not to write 'dev' or 'test' in condition myself, but to read `true` or `false` from yaml files.

For example: `condition = "@serviceEnabled == true"`, does not work.

```java
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {

    @Value("${page-cache.starting}")
    private Boolean serviceEnabled;

   // means that when running dev will be false and the method will not run and this code is working
    @EventListener(
        value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class,
        condition = "@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] != 'dev'")
    public void updateCacheAfterStartup() {
        log.info("Info add starting...");
        someService.getInfo();
    }
}
```

I tried to do as in this article, but it doesn't work for me:

[Evaluate property from properties file in Spring's @EventListener(condition = "...")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723383/evaluate-property-from-properties-file-in-springs-eventlistenercondition)

I also tried the same option

```java
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {
    @Value("${page-cache.starting}")
    private Boolean serviceEnabled;
   
    public Boolean isServiceEnabled() {
        return this.serviceEnabled;
    }

    public Boolean getServiceEnabled() {
        return serviceEnabled;
    }

    @EventListener(
        value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class,
        condition = "@ServiceImpl.serviceEnabled")
    public void updateCacheAfterStartup() {
        log.info("Info add starting...");
        someService.getInfo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the YAML format is correct in `application-test.yml`, `application-prd.yml`,...

   example:

   `application-dev.yml`

   ```yaml
   page-cache:
      starting: false
   ```
2. `ServiceImpl` must be a component/bean, so annotate your class with `@Service`, `@Component` or use `@Bean` if the instance is created in a `@Configuration` class.

*Extra tip:*

You could use  `condition = "! @environment.acceptsProfiles('dev')"`

instead of `condition = "@environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] != 'dev'"`

that way the order of active profiles does not matter

or define when the condition is valid:  `condition = "@environment.acceptsProfiles('test', 'prod')"`

**UPDATE:**

You could also directly use `page-cache.starting` in the condition.

```java
@EventListener(
     value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class,
     condition = "@environment.getProperty('page-cache.starting')")
public void updateCacheAfterStartup() {
    // update the cache
}
```

Here `updateCacheAfterStartup()` will only be triggered at startup when `page-cache.starting` is `true`. If set to `false` or when **not present** the method will not be called.

If you want to force that `page-cache.starting` is provided (in all profiles) you should use: `condition="@environment.getRequiredProperty('page-cache.starting')"`

Comment: you wrote everything correctly, that's exactly what I'm following. But I don't want to rigidly prescribe the profile name in condition, but I want to take it from yaml. So far the attempts are not successful

Answer (score 0):

you can access the property using `@Value` in some class whose bean is created (either by annotations Component, Service, Configuration .. etc.). Use `@EventListener(condition = "@beanName.youProperty")`, the event is handled when the value of `yourProperty` is `true` or string having "true", "on", "yes", or "1" values.

if `yourProperty` is private and doesn't have getter also, then above will fail. `yourProperty` on the bean should be either public or should have getter if private.

in your case:

```
public class ServiceImpl{

   @Value("${page-cache.starting}")
   private Boolean serviceEnabled;

   // can be getServiceEnabled
   public Boolean isServiceEnabled() { 
    return this.serviceEnabled;
   }

   @EventListener(
        value = ApplicationReadyEvent.class,
        condition = "@serviceImpl.serviceEnabled")
   public void updateCacheAfterStartup() {
    log.info("Info add starting...");
   someService.getInfo();
}
```